# Does Pluto's atmosphere collapse?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, pluto

There were theories that Pluto's atmosphere collapses when it gets too far from the sun.

Then I've read [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05672) that says that it [doesn't](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2013/09051420-plutos-atmosphere-does-not-collapse.html).

But [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/new-horizons-reveals-pluto-s-atmospheric-pressure-has-sharply-decreased) says that the surface pressure went down recently (implying that it does).

Is there any clear data as to what's going on?

Comment: Similar to Mars, Pluto's atmosphere can freeze on it's surface and later return to the atmosphere depending on temperature.   The same thing happens on Earth with water vapor, but water's a tiny fraction of our atmosphere.   Pluto may also be undergoing some gradual outgassing and permanent loss of it's surface, to atmosphere, to space, but I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 4):

Found this link by Emily Lakdawalla, she wrote a detailed explanation about Pluto`s seasons and its movement thru the solar system. Here research seems to contradict the atmosphere collapse and and here 3 models and research on Pluto. Seems the most likely model gives the highest pressure in the atmosphere between 2020 ad 2040, but none a atmosphere collapse. [source](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2013/09051420-plutos-atmosphere-does-not-collapse.html)

Comment: +1 for mentioning Ms. Lakdawalla.  She and Phil Plait are the best references you can find for astronomy topics.